# Tempo Markings following rit and rall

Tags: notation

Tempo marking following a rit or rall. What is a rit and what is a rall?

Answer (score 3):

'rit' = *ritardando*

'rall' = *rallentando*

Both mean 'getting slower' - [Ritardando, Rallentando, and Allargando](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31736/ritardando-rallentando-and-allargando) should explain in more detail.

Comment: Somewhere in my readings regarding Mahler's 2cd there was a mention that his tempo markings followed a .rit and/or a rall. Did not know what the writer was referring to with these terms. Thank you for the clarification.